# Change detection on varbinary fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

The following tables enable me to load and store simple compressed text files in MS SQL Server database:
(The compressed files are small, so I have no performance issues, and also not really related to my question below)

```
create table StagingDocument
(
...
DocumentID uniqueidentifier,
DocumentData nvarchar(max)
...
)

create table ClientDocument
(
...
DocumentID uniqueidentifier,
DocumentData varbinary(max)
...
)
```

DocumentID is a natural key for the document and uniquely identifies a document,
DocumentData column is the document itself.

I load and compress documents like this:

```
INSERT INTO ClientDocument(DocumentID,DocumentData)
SELECT s.DocumentID, COMPRESS(DocumentData) --note how the document is compressed
FROM StagingDocument s
```

...

Imagine, you have to select the documents (identified by DocumentID) from Staging table,
which are already in the Client table but their content has changed (DocumentData differs),
then you write something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM StagingDocument s
INNER JOIN ClientDocument d ON s.DocumentID = d.DocumentID AND COMPRESS(s.DocumentData) <> d.DocumentData
```

Of course the COMPRESS add enormous overhead here, it just for demoing purposes.

My question is:

What is the best way to compare if DocumentData has changed?

1. Is it good enough if I change the staging nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) (have the client insert compressed data to staging directly), then just compare the varbinary fields like this?

   ... AND s.DocumentData <> d.DocumentData

I think it's good enough, since the GZIP algorithm behind COMPRESS function produces different varbinary results for different texts,
so there could be no collision ever.

2. Should I calculate hash on the human readable nvarchar DocumentData in the Staging table, then compare those hash values instead of the varbinary(max) fields?
   SHA2_256 hash would give me binary(32) results. Would that be faster to compare than varbinary?
3. Should I calculate hash on the varbinary(max) fields?
   I am not familiar how hash functions would react. Would my hash collision chance increase?

I think #1 is good enough, but would be nice to hear somebody else's opinion too.

Comment: If the values are reasonably small and performance isn't a concern, I agree "good enough" is good enough.

Comment: Does "change" include the possibility of something changing back to what it was before, while still counting as a change? In that case you'll need an explicit date/time field to distinguish that, which incidentally also provides an alternative to directly comparing the value.

Comment: your one field is `nvarchar` type another is `varbinary` type, how these 2 fields are comparable directly `AND s.DocumentData <> d.DocumentData`....i'm confused

Comment: @DarkRob, implicit conversion varbinary to nvarchar is possible.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin: please check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/473f5/1

Comment: @DarkRob right, in that case I would utilize varbinary in the staging table as well, and ... let me add that clarification in there

Comment: @JeroenMostert Didn't show, but I actually have a date in that table, and do use it. Good point.

Comment: @DanGuzman "small" equals to under 4000 thousand, mostly between 1-3000 ... is that considered big?

Comment: @DarkRob, you made a mistake there, check this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/473f5/2

Comment: @DanGuzman the comparison should perform the best which boils down to a binary(32) vs varbinary(1-3000) ... so should i be afraid of the varbinary comparison performance wise?

Comment: @Avithohol, IMHO, the difference will not be perceptable if the values are stored in-row, which I would expect with smaller value slike this.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin: thanks for your time, in my fiddle that was not mistake, I actually write it as OP mention in our query and found that ans is not as explained....so my point is, is there something missing which I didn't get it. Thankfully it is not.... :) As it is corrected now... `COMPRESS(s.DocumentData) <> d.DocumentData`

Comment: @Avithohol can you put timestamp column or version control column in your stage table and main table?

Comment: @MahdiRahimi not really unfortunately

Comment: @Avithohol can you add one or two new table for save the state or version of your file?